# Changing IDoc segment SDATA via field-symbols?

Tags: abap

My scenario is that I am getting an IDOC segment's data into a field symbol and change some fields based on some validations.

My code:

```
READ TABLE idoc_data ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<idocdata>) with key = 'E1EDK01'
IF sy-subrc = 0.

    lcl_struc ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( 'E1EDK01' ).
    CREATE DATA dref TYPE HANDLE lcl_struc.
    ASSIGN dref->* TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<sdata>).

    IF <sdata> IS ASSIGNED.
      <sdata> = <idocdata>-sdata. 
      ....
      <idocdata>-sdata = <sdata>.
    ENDIF. 
ENDIF.
```

Though the above snippet works fine, the continuity of field symbols is broken and now I have to pass back the changed data. How do I use `ASSIGN` and let the field symbols take care of the changes rather than an explicit statement?

Something similar to below snippet though this won't work since `<IDOC_DATA>-SDATA` and `<SDATA>` aren't compatible.

```
READ TABLE idoc_data ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<idocdata>) with key = 'E1EDK01'
IF sy-subrc = 0.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS: <sdata> TYPE E1EDK01.
    ASSIGN <idocdata>-sdata TO <sdata>.
    ....
ENDIF.
```

My expectation is that when I change the data in `<SDATA>-FIELD1`, I want the changes to flow into `<IDOCDATA>-SDATA` without using `<idocdata>-sdata = <sdata>`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "the continuity of field symbols is broken". Can you explain that in a different way and elaborate on why it is a problem?

Comment: I think that the second snippet would work if you used an untyped field-symbol (just  `FIELD-SYMBOLS <sdata>.`). But now you have a field-symbol without a type which might cause other typing problems down the line. Depending on what `"Logic goes here` means, this might or might not be a problem which can or can't be easily solved.

Comment: @Philipp 
My expectation is that when I change the data in `<SDATA>-FIELD1`, I want the changes to flow into `<IDOCDATA>-SDATA` without using `<idocdata>-sdata = <sdata>`.

Comment: @Philipp The issue is IDOCDATA-SDATA is of type `CHAR1000`. Even if I dynamically get the data by `FIELD-SYMBOL (<sdata>)` ,  `<sdata>` also becomes `CHAR1000`. My intention is to transform the data into a specific structure.

In classical, it would be like this:
`DATA: WA_SDATA type E1EDK01.
MOVE <IDOCDATA>-SDATA to WA_SDATA.`

Comment: Is there a good reason why the solution which copies the data to a dynamically created structure and then back into `<idocdata>` is insufficient in your case? When your main argument is "It does not look elegant" - well, I could think of a workaround, but that one would look even less elegant.

Comment: @Philipp As a part of my learning process, I am just looking at possibilities on how this can be handled in different ways or if it can be written based on my thought process.

Comment: I think your 2nd example has the exact syntax error `<IDOCDATA>-SDATA" and "<SDATA>" have incompatible types`. It just needs CASTING: `ASSIGN <idocdata>-sdata TO <sdata> CASTING.`

Comment: @SandraRossi always to the rescue. Yes, exactly what I was looking for. I never really understood the usecase of `CAST`. Is there anything I should be careful of using `CAST` in this scenario?

Comment: In your scenario, CASTING should work without any issue because the structures of IDoc segments should contain only character-like fields (C, N, D, T).

Answer (score 2):

As @Sandra mentioned above, the incompatibility of field-symbols can be resolved by using `CASTING` while assigning them. This would make the second snippet work.

```
...
IF sy-subrc = 0.
   FIELD-SYMBOLS: <sdata> TYPE E1EDK01.
   ASSIGN <idocdata>-sdata TO <sdata> CASTING.
   ...
ENDIF.
```